# Conditional parameters in an Ecto Query

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I've got a parameter `platform` which is optional:

```
def query_clicks(freq \\ "day", platform \\ false) do
    from(Click)
    |> select(
      [c],
      [
        fragment("date_trunc(?,?) as t", ^freq, c.inserted_at), count(c.link_id) ]
      )
      |> if platform, do: fn(q) -> where([c], c.platform == ^platform) end, else: fn(q): q end
    |> group_by([c], fragment("t"))
    |> Repo.all
  end
```

I've tried to hack something in (see "if platform..."), but I'm not sure of the exact syntax to use. What I want to do is:

```
if platform != None:
  return query + WHERE statement
else:
  return query
```

What's the right syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add an extra function `maybe_platform/2`

```
defp maybe_platform(queryable, nil), do: queryable
defp maybe_platform(queryable, platform) do
  queryable
  |> where([c], c.platform == ^platform)
end
```

Then your `query_clicks/2` looks like

```
def query_clicks(freq \\ "day", platform \\ false) do
  from(Click)
  |> select(
    [c],
    [
      fragment("date_trunc(?,?) as t", ^freq, c.inserted_at), count(c.link_id) 
    ]
  )
  |> maybe_platform(platform)
  |> group_by([c], fragment("t"))
  |> Repo.all
end
```

It can be done in a anonymous function like you did but this is a little clearer imo.

Comment: That's really great, thanks. How can I generalise it? I tried use Code.eval_string("c.#{param}"), [c: c, param: param]), but that didn't compile

Comment: You could look into https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.API.html#field/2

Answer (score 0):

This might be too late but I just wanted to share my solution to this problem.
Make use of the fact that piping a queryable through any method of [Ecto macro api](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.html#module-macro-api) such as `where`, `select`, `limit`, `offset` etc. still returns a queryable.
so it can be done by a simple if:

```
def query_clicks(freq \\ "day", platform \\ false) do
  query = from(Click) |> select(...)

  (if platform, do: where(query, [c], c.platform == ^platform), else: query)
  |> group_by([c], fragment("t"))
  |> Repo.all
end
```

Its less code. Hope it helps :)